# is it possible to establish rabbitMQ connection with javax.jms (not using rabbitMQ jms client/ java client )? if yes how?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

is it possible to establish rabbitMQ connection with javax.jms (not using rabbitMQ jms client/ java client )? if yes how (not with springboot).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. RabbitMQ provides a class implementing JMS Connection factory [com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-java-client/api/current/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.html):

```
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new Connection().newConnection();

    // create a Connection
    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.setClientID(clientId);

    // create a Session
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // create the Topic from which messages will be received
    Topic topic = session.createTopic(topicName);

    // create a MessageConsumer for receiving messages
    messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(topic);

    // start the connection in order to receive messages
    connection.start();
```

Except for the first line (Factory creation), this is pure JMS code.

Answer (score -1):

You either need to use the driver or write your own driver.  You should not expect anyone here to write it for you.  What have you tried?